# JSPX EL 2.2 method calling using EL 2.1

Tags: el, jspx

I have JSP that works fine in Tomcat 7 but does not work in Tomcat 6 which I assume is the fact that you cannot call methods (other than getters/setter) from EL 2.1.

The method I need to call cannot be named as a getter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a workaround and thought I would post the answer:

If you have Spring installed you can use Spring EL so that you can call methods on objects

For example:

```
<spring:eval expression="pic.thumbnailUrl()" var="thumbnail" />
```

Comment: This works great for me! I've needed this functionality quite many times. I had tried installing EL-2.2 into Tomcat 6.0 but that didn't work for me.. Once again Spring saves the day.